# authWithCustomToken not firing callback

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When a user registers on my system, I create the user internally, and then allow the user to register with Firebase using the firebase client lib. This generates a session token for the user. Later, when a user starts the app again, the app automatically logs the user in like this:

```
ref.authWithCustomToken(sessionToken, function(error, authData) {...
  debugger
```

I have verified that the sessionToken is available when the function is executed, but `debugger` is never reached, and no error is ever emitted.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not enough here to reproduce the error. Version info, settings in your app dashboard, whether you're using Ionic/Cordova/Other, lots of other factors could contribute here, as you can probably imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but I experienced a similar problem and it had me scratching my head for a while, so just in case it helps somebody else, here's what I found.

If I run `authWithCustomToken` with a token generated with one uid (uid1) and then run it again on the same ref with a different uid (uid2), the callback doesn't get fired the second time around.

In my case, I had declared the same ref in different modules that were used in the same node process and was trying to authenticate them with different uids. Although I had declared the ref twice, Firebase still saw it as the same ref because it was in the same process and referred to the same Firebase location. By declaring and authorising the ref in a parent module, I was then able to use `onAuth` in the child modules and the `onAuth` callbacks all fired as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with iOS, authWithCustomToken callback was never called right after install. 
All consecutive launches worked fine.
My findings might be related so I thought I share them.

Problem was I called

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    Firebase.goOffline()
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    Firebase.goOnline()
}
```

in AppDelegate. Turns out if you call Firebase.goOnline() without logging in first it messes up the callback. Once I removed those two lines everything worked fine.